# having issue in activity jumping

Tags: android, android-activity

i am developing simple login activity. on clicking **send to next screen button** , it must jump to another activity but it is giving error  **unfortunately activity stopped working** & close my app. how to overcome this issue?

my java code of first activity is

```
package com.project.whoami;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class FirstScreenActivity extends Activity {
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputEmail;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen1);
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    Button btnNextScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNextScreen);

  //Listening to button event
    btnNextScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Starting a new Intent
            Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondScreenActivity.class);

            //Sending data to another Activity
            nextScreen.putExtra("name", inputName.getText().toString());
            nextScreen.putExtra("email", inputEmail.getText().toString());

            Log.e("n", inputName.getText()+"."+ inputEmail.getText());

            startActivity(nextScreen);

        }
    });
}
}
```

my java code for second activity

```
package com.project.whoami;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondScreenActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

        TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        TextView txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        Button btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        // Receiving the Data
        String name = i.getStringExtra("name");
        String email = i.getStringExtra("email");
        Log.e("Second Screen", name + "." + email);

        // Displaying Received data
        txtName.setText(name);
        txtEmail.setText(email);

        // Binding Click event to Button
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Closing SecondScreen Activity
                finish();
            }

            private void finish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }


}
```

Comment: Paste your logcat details too

Comment: may be your edittext are null.....logcat please

Comment: make sure the second activity is declared in manifest

Answer (score 0):

check your android manifest file declare the second activity there..